# How to document multiple content types in successful GET response in swagger

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui

Let's say we have an example json swagger spec:

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Some API"
},
"basePath": "/api/v1",
"consumes": [
    "application/json"
],
"produces": [
    "application/json",
    "text/csv"
],
"paths": {
    "/some/endpoint": {
        "get": {
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "in": "body",
                    "name": "body",
                    "required": false,
                    "schema": {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/BodyParamsDefinition"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": { ?? } ...
```

There are two content types that can be produced:

- application/json
- text/csv

Default response for `GET /some/endpoint` is a csv file, but if the `format` query param is used like this `/some/endpoint?format=json`, the response would be in json format.

I have trouble finding how should I finish my specification with proper responses.
When I use this approach: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/ i get a validation error: `...get.responses['200'] should NOT have additional properties`

Comment: The doc you linked to is for OpenAPI 3.0, the 2.0 version is https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-responses/

Comment: Also, GET operations are not supposed to have a body.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need to define a `schema` for the response. This `schema` defines the response structure for all content types associated with this status code.

For example, if the operation returns this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "petType": "dog",
    "name": "Fluffy"
  },
  {
    "petType": "cat",
    "name": "Crookshanks"
  }
]
```

and this CSV:

```
petType,name
dog,Fluffy
cat,Crookshanks
```

you would use:

```yaml
# YAML
responses:
  200:
    description: OK
    schema:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
        properties:
          petType:
            type: string
          name:
            type: string
```

More info: [Describing Responses](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-responses/)

In OpenAPI 3.0, content type definitions were improved and schemas can vary by content type:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

paths:
  /some/endpoint:
    get:
      responses:
       '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            # JSON data is an object
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  message:
                    type: string
            # CSV data is a string of text
            text/csv:
              schema:
                type: string
```

> Default response for `GET /some/endpoint` is a csv file, but if the `format` query param is used like this `/some/endpoint?format=json`, the response would be in json format.

There's currently no way to map specific responses to specific operation parameters, but there are several related proposals in the OpenAPI Specification repository:

- [Accommodate legacy APIs by allowing query parameters in the path](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/123)
- [Querystring in Path Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/164)
- [Support an operation to have multiple specifications per path](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/182)
- [Overloading](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/298)

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive answer. That was very helpful.

Comment: @PawełDudziński: If this answered your question, please tick the check mark on left side to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/131247).