# Generate OpenAPI client with multiple request / response content types, a custom (de)serializer, and discriminators

Tags: typescript, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

First, an OpenAPI spec. This is simplified to just demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish, all of these components are more complex in reality:

```
---
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: My API
  version: 0.1.0
paths:
  "/transaction":
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "hey"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/OnChainTransaction"
            application/x-bcs:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/OnChainTransaction"
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/SubmitTransactionRequest'
          application/x-bcs:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/SubmitTransactionRequest'
      responses:
        "202":
          description: "hey"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/PendingTransaction'
            application/x-bcs:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/PendingTransaction'
components:
  schemas:
    OnChainTransaction:
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/GenesisTransaction'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserTransaction'
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type
    GenesisTransaction:
      type: string
    UserTransaction:
      type: string
    SubmitTransactionRequest:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserTransactionRequest'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserTransactionSignature'
    UserTransactionRequest:
      type: string
    UserTransactionSignature:
      type: string
    PendingTransaction:
      required:
        - transaction
      properties:
        transaction:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/OnChainTransaction'
```

You'll note the use of `x-bcs`. BCS is a custom serialization method.

So with this spec, I want the client to be able to do the following:

- Send a request to the POST endpoints as either JSON or BCS (using `Content-Type`).
- Use `Accept` to tell the server what format to return the response in (JSON or BCS).
- Use discriminators, like oneOf and allOf for both requests and responses.
- Automatically serialize and deserialize BCS within the generated client.

So far I have been unable to find a TS based OpenAPI generator that supports all of these features natively. I have tried [openapi-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-typescript), [swagger-typescript-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-typescript-api), and [all the TS generators](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/) in `openapi-generator`.

How can I invoke one of these TS generators to generate a client that acknowledges that there are multiple input / output types, understands discriminator types, and allows me to inject a function to serialize and deserialize the data for BCS format? It should also not just generate interfaces, but functions for making requests and processing responses.

Other relevant links:

- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/144
- [How to document multiple content types in successful GET response in swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694530/how-to-document-multiple-content-types-in-successful-get-response-in-swagger)

Comment: I like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-typescript-codegen and use it with axios. It produces nice, readable code, that does not look generated. It could be a good base, in case you have to implement the functionality you are missing.

Comment: For anyone coming along later, I did use this generator @HEllRZA suggested. Note however that it doesn't solve the custom (de)serializer problem and it has turned out that the author is not receptive to fairly fundamental changes that need to be made to make it comply with the OpenAPI standard: https://github.com/ferdikoomen/openapi-typescript-codegen/issues/1295. So in short, I don't recommend this library anymore.